# How to create a cursor for input text?

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I'm creating a web game where the user types a *HTML* code on a screen and the other displays the code result and I'm trying to create a cursor for a input area. It has a blink animation and has to move as the user types something. The edition screen is as follows:

[image]

I think that changing the default cursor of input is pretty difficult so I searched for creating the square but I couldn't move it with the cursor. So what I need is:

- The page needs, when it loads, to put the cursor on input (without the user clicks on it).
- Create a bigger cursor that follows the input cursor
- Make the input size be dynamic. It's size needs to grow as the user types (I think this is a better way to make the cursor moves)

I'm using *AngularJS* in this project. One problem that I had: my input text was moving to left too as I typed, so I need to make the input increases just to right.

Comment: 1, document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     yourTargetInput.focus();
  });
2. Use an image for the cursor and resize it according to input.lenght.
3 following the typing is will be hacky...very.
I can think of either roughly calculating and moving the cursor with every new letter. Or placing a span within the input field with flexible and animatable width.

I did not post an answer because you said the FW is Angular, which I am not familiar with

Comment: You can use/get inspired by this library https://github.com/mad4j/curses.js